# KVM guests crash after Ubuntu upgrade to 14.04

Tags: kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-14.04

On our way to the latest Ubuntu LTS we've recently upgraded a KVM server from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04, but now it's virtual machines are unable to boot. I'm afraid continuing upgrading the system in a broken state might make the problem worse.

The upgrade went fine, apart from some hiccups with LVM snapshots which I've resolved.

When a virtual machine crashes there's nothing remarkble in the logs of the host machine.

I've tried booting a bare vm without a NIC or Harddisk, just booting a live Ubuntu iso, but that also didn't work. Windows vm's fail to boot too.

The only suspicious thing showing up in the host logs is this in the dmesg:

```
[   86.809494] cgroup: systemd-logind (1168) created nested cgroup for controller "memory" which has incomplete hierarchy support. Nested cgroups may change be
havior in the future.                                                                                                                                          
[   86.809499] cgroup: "memory" requires setting use_hierarchy to 1 on the root.
```

I've managed to capture the output of an Ubuntu guest until it crashes over the serial interface. This is the output right before the kernel panic:

```
[    1.323260] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    1.324122] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[    1.325102] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.326357] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input1
[    1.328120] rtc_cmos 00:00: RTC can wake from S4
[    1.329176] rtc_cmos 00:00: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
[    1.330329] rtc_cmos 00:00: alarms up to one day, 114 bytes nvram
[    1.331360] i2c /dev entries driver
[    1.331991] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    1.332854] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.34.0-ioctl (2015-10-28) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    1.334288] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    1.335634] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    1.336650] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.337440] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    1.338291] microcode: AMD CPU family 0xf not supported
[    1.339288] registered taskstats version 1
[    1.339970] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    1.342042] Loaded X.509 cert 'Build time autogenerated kernel key: a4cff54e0cc9179d8dcdcbb195a5dba42f5df569'
[    1.343736] zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud
[    1.344712] PANIC: double fault, error_code: 0x0
[    1.345495] CPU: 0 PID: 67 Comm: modprobe Not tainted 4.4.0-70-generic #91-Ubuntu
[    1.346758] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS Bochs 01/01/2011
[    1.348018] task: ffff880000a30cc0 ti: ffff88001e814000 task.ti: ffff88001e814000
[    1.348468] RIP: 0010:[<0000000000000000>]  [<          (null)>]           (null)
[    1.348468] RSP: 0018:00007ffe29ea5018  EFLAGS: 00010246
[    1.348468] RAX: 000000000000000c RBX: 0000000000000001 RCX: 00007f14331fa2e9
[    1.348468] RDX: 00007ffe29ea5280 RSI: 000055a0b7bd1310 RDI: 0000000000000000
[    1.348468] RBP: 000055a0b7bce040 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: 00007ffe29ea52a9
[    1.348468] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000009
[    1.348468] R13: 00007f14331e19a0 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: 0000000000001000
[    1.348468] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88001fc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[    1.348468] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
[    1.348468] CR2: 00007ffe29ea4ff8 CR3: 000000001efdf000 CR4: 00000000000006f0
[    1.348468] Stack:
[    1.348468]  00007f14331f9305 00007ffe29ea5299 00007ffe29eae000 0001010000000000
[    1.348468]  0001037f00000064 0000000000000000 00000000078bfbfd 0000000000000000
[    1.348468]  000055a0b7bd1310 0000000000000000 0000000000000001 00007ffe29ea5100
[    1.348468] Call Trace:
[    1.348468]  <UNK> 
[    1.348468] Code:  Bad RIP value.
[    1.348468] Kernel panic - not syncing: Machine halted.
[    1.348468] CPU: 0 PID: 67 Comm: modprobe Not tainted 4.4.0-70-generic #91-Ubuntu
[    1.348468] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS Bochs 01/01/2011
[    1.348468]  0000000000000086 00000000e094cae7 ffff88001fc04e80 ffffffff813f82b3
[    1.348468]  ffffffff81cb7ebc ffff88001fc04f18 ffff88001fc04f08 ffffffff8118d367
[    1.348468]  0000000000000008 ffff88001fc04f18 ffff88001fc04eb0 00000000e094cae7
[    1.348468] Call Trace:
[    1.348468]  <#DF>  [<ffffffff813f82b3>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[    1.348468]  [<ffffffff8118d367>] panic+0xd3/0x215
[    1.348468]  [<ffffffff81060d1d>] df_debug+0x2d/0x30
[    1.348468]  [<ffffffff8102fb8c>] do_double_fault+0x7c/0xf0
[    1.348468]  [<ffffffff8183e1f8>] double_fault+0x28/0x30
[    1.348468]  <<EOE>>  <UNK> 
[    1.348468] Kernel Offset: disabled
[    1.348468] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Machine halted.
```

(This is not the complete log, because StackExchange thinks it's spam)

Package versions:

- Kernel: 3.13.0-169-generic #219-Ubuntu
- qemu-kvm: 2.0.0+dfsg-2ubuntu1.45
- libvirt-bin: 1.2.2-0ubuntu13.1.27

Command executed by libvirt:

```
LC_ALL=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none /usr/bin/kvm-spice -name borkum -S -machine pc-i440fx-trusty,acc
el=kvm,usb=off -cpu Opteron_G3 -m 512 -realtime mlock=off -smp 1,sockets=1,cores=1,threads=1 -uuid acee95a1-b2e2-470c-85d7-89d85aceddc4 -no-user-config -nodefa
ults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/borkum.monitor,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc base=utc,drif
tfix=slew -global kvm-pit.lost_tick_policy=discard -no-hpet -no-shutdown -boot strict=on -device ich9-usb-ehci1,id=usb,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5 -device ich9-usb-uhci
1,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6 -device ich9-usb-uhci2,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=2,bus=pci.0,addr=0x7 -device ich9-usb-uhci3,masterbus=usb.0,f
irstport=4,bus=pci.0,addr=0x8 -device virtio-serial-pci,id=virtio-serial0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x9 -drive file=/dev/images/borkum,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,forma
t=raw,cache=none,aio=native -device virtio-blk-pci,scsi=off,bus=pci.0,addr=0xa,drive=drive-virtio-disk0,id=virtio-disk0,bootindex=1 -drive if=none,id=drive-ide
0-0-0,readonly=on,format=raw -device ide-cd,bus=ide.0,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-0-0,id=ide0-0-0 -netdev tap,fd=24,id=hostnet0,vhost=on,vhostfd=25 -device virtio-
net-pci,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:aa:55:a8,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 -chardev pty,id=charserial0 -device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 -chardev
 spicevmc,id=charchannel0,name=vdagent -device virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=1,chardev=charchannel0,id=channel0,name=com.redhat.spice.0 -vnc 127.0.0.1
:0 -device cirrus-vga,id=video0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x2 -device intel-hda,id=sound0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4 -device hda-duplex,id=sound0-codec0,bus=sound0.0,cad=0 -devic
e virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0xb
```

VM config file:

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>borkum</name>
  <uuid>acee95a1-b2e2-470c-85d7-89d85aceddc4</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>524288</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>524288</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>1</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-trusty'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact'>
    <model fallback='allow'>Opteron_G3</model>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm-spice</emulator>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
      <source dev='/dev/images/borkum'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x0a' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>
      <master startport='0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci2'>
      <master startport='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci3'>
      <master startport='4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x09' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'/>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:aa:55:a8'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <channel type='spicevmc'>
      <target type='virtio' name='com.redhat.spice.0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </channel>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes'/>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type='cirrus' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x0b' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

In /etc/libvirt libvirt.conf and qemu.conf do not contain any adjusted settings, everything is default. libvirtd.conf is stock, save for these lines:

```
unix_sock_group = "libvirtd"
unix_sock_ro_perms = "0777"
unix_sock_rw_perms = "0770"
auth_unix_ro = "none"
auth_unix_rw = "none"
```

So, how to get these vm's booting again, so we can continue upgrading?

**edit: I ended up installing a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 over the broken 14.04 installation, preserving the vm disks. This fixed the issue, the vm's boot now.**

Comment: have a look here, maybe thats your issue?
https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=13241
for now it looks memory related,
given that a lot have changed in the time between 12.04 and 14.04 i would search for something like a specific memory mapping option which changed the default value.
random guess: Is this on the same hardware? BIOS checked?, empty battery perhaps? VT-X now disabled?
given that you are a few versions behind and it might be worth checking into if you can switch to a completly new install of 18.04 f.e. (unless you are a customer of canonical, but even then i would update.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 is past end of life. Update to a supported Ubuntu release.

Comment: @DennisNolte Thanks for the suggestions, I'll look into that. This is on the same hardware.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I know, we were on our way upgrading to the latest LTS, but I'm afraid to continue upgrading a system that's not working. Since it was the upgrade that caused the problems in the first place. Although if nothing else works I just might give that a shot.

Comment: If you can't paste the whole kernel log, the *end* is likely to be more useful than the beginning.  Also the exact package versions of relevant things will be helpful, as well as the exact command / libvirt config you're using to boot a failing VM.

Comment: @womble The end is also in there up to the kernel panic. I cut the middle to make it shorter. I left the beginning in because it contains information about the system, but if that's not useful I'll take it out. I'll edit my question to add the relevant package versions, thanks.

Comment: Can you repro the problem on a freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04 system?  That'll isolate whether it's an upgrade problem or an Ubuntu 14.04 problem.